# Scala types: Class A is not equal to the T where T is: type T = A

Tags: scala, types, path-dependent-type

I was reading the section 20.7 of the book Programming in Scala and I was wondering why while this code compiles:

```
class Food
class Fish extends Food
class Grass extends Food

abstract class Animal {
  type SuitableFood <: Food
  def eat(food: SuitableFood)
}


class Cow extends Animal {
  type SuitableFood = Grass
  override def eat(food: Grass) {}
}


val bessy: Animal = new Cow

bessy eat (new bessy.SuitableFood)
```

This code does not (the rest of the code is the same as before, only the last line changes):

```
bessy eat (new Grass)
```

And as far as I understand the type of Grass is the same of Cow.SuitableFood.

Also, I have another question regarding this example:

If bessy is of type Animal, how can the compiler know that it needs a type SuitableFood -> Grass instead of a type Food? 'Cause trying to provide a new Food gives me a compile error of type mismatch, but the class Animal needs a type Food and the type of bessy is explicitly defined: Animal

Comment: Suggestion: add the tag _path-dependent-type_ to this question. That might attract an answer from someone who knows more about exactly this kind of difficulty. (I'm still struggling with path-dependent types myself.)

Comment: @BenKovitz Added, thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's because `bessie` is declared `Animal` rather than `Cow`. `bessie.SuitableFood` is a "path-dependent type" (see below).

Try this:

```
val clarabelle: Cow = new Cow

clarabelle eat (new Grass)
```

This works because the compiler *can* deduce that `clarabelle.SuitableFood = Grass` from `clarabelle`'s declared type.

Since `bessie` is declared `Animal`, not `Cow`, the compiler can't safely deduce that `bessie.SuitableFood = Grass`.* When you say `new bessie.SuitableFood`, the compiler generates code to look at the actual `bessie` object and generate a new instance of the appropriate type. `bessie.SuitableFood` is a "path-dependent type": the "[path](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html#paths)" (the `bessie.` part) that leads to the last identifier (`SuitableFood`) is actually part of the type. This enables you to have a custom version of a type for each individual object of the same class.

---

*<sub>Well, actually, I think that if the compiler were a little smarter, it could deduce that `bessie.SuitableFood = Grass`, since `bessie` is a `val`, not a `var`, and therefore won't change its type. In other words, the compiler ought to know that even though `bessie` is declared `Animal`, she's really a `Cow`. Perhaps a future version of the compiler will make use of this knowledge, and perhaps there's a good reason why that wouldn't be a good idea, which someone more expert than I will tell us. (Postscript: One just did! See Travis Brown's comment below.)</sub>

Comment: About your footnote: if you put a type annotation on something, the compiler is going to treat it as that type, even if it _could_ infer something more specific. You'd need to use a type refinement like `val bessy: Animal { type SuitableFood = Grass }` if you wanted to keep track of the type member but not the subtype.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the second part of your question: it doesn't. `Animal` doesn't specify that its food is `Food`, but some subtype of `Food`. Would the compiler accept this, code like your example would compile, and wrongly so. The compiler doesn't know that the necessary subtype is `Grass` (which is why `eat(new Grass)` doesn't work either), it just knows that there are some foods your cow can't eat and is cautious about it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe `bessy eat (new bessy.SuitableFood)` compiling is a bug (which was fixed in 2.11). Because another subtype of `Animal` could have a `SuitableFood` for which `new` makes no sense, e.g. `type SuitableFood = Food` or even `type SuitableFood = Food with Int` (`Food with Int` is a perfectly nice subtype of `Food`!).