# Path Dependent Types example doesn't work

Tags: scala, path-dependent-type

Scala n00b here. Pretty sure I understand PDT's but was making sure and hit a problem; here's a previous question [Scala types: Class A is not equal to the T where T is: type T = A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32161100/scala-types-class-a-is-not-equal-to-the-t-where-t-is-type-t-a) with sample code which I'll reproduce here:

```
1: class Food
2: class Fish extends Food
3: class Grass extends Food
4:
5: abstract class Animal {
  6: type SuitableFood <: Food
  7: def eat(food: SuitableFood)
8: }
9: 
10: class Cow extends Animal {
  11: type SuitableFood = Grass
  12: override def eat(food: Grass) {}
13: }
14: 
15: val bessy: Animal = new Cow  // [1]
16: 
17: bessy eat (new bessy.SuitableFood) // [2]
```

The original poster said this compiled, I believe it should, but it won't. If I paste it into the scala REPL it successfully creates bessy [1]:

```
scala> val bessy: Animal = new Cow
bessy: Animal = Cow@165b8a71
```

but [2], gives me an error which I don't understand:

```
scala> bessy.eat(bessy.SuitableFood)
<console>:17: error: value SuitableFood is not a member of Animal
       bessy.eat(bessy.SuitableFood)
                       ^
```

If I paste it into a file and 'scalac' it, I get the same. Why? `bessy` is a cow object, `type SuitableFood = Grass` is defined therein, `bessy.SuitableFood` is a a class type (isn't it?).
What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are missing `new` in `(new bessy.SuitableFood)`.
2. After you fix this, `bessy` is defined to have type `Animal`, not `Cow`, so the compiler *doesn't* know `bessy.SuitableFood` is `Grass`: it's just an abstract type, so `new bessy.SuitableFood` doesn't work (like `new A` doesn't when `A` is a type parameter). E.g. consider that some other subtype of `Animal` could declare `type SuitableFood = Food`, and `new Food` is illegal.
   I've checked, and it does compile in 2.10.6, but I believe it's a bug which was fixed.

> Hence I thought "new bessy.SuitableFood" would return a suitable food because .SuitableFood would be a kind of virtual type, so when  is 'Cow' then 'SuitableFood' would be 'grass'. I don't see the value of PDTs if they don't do this.

The point of PDTs here is that if you *do* have a `bessy.SuitableFood`, `bessy` can eat it; and she can't eat `spot.SuitableFood` (unless the compiler can *statically* know it's a subtype). But this example doesn't give any way to produce a `bessy.SuitableFood`, because there is no reason to assume (and no way to tell the compiler) `type SuitableFood` is a class with a public parameterless constructor. You can fix it by adding a method to `Animal`:

```
abstract class Animal {
  type SuitableFood <: Food
  def eat(food: SuitableFood)
  def newSuitableFood(): SuitableFood
}

class Cow extends Animal {
  ...
  def newSuitableFood() = new Grass
}
```

Now `bessy.eat(bessy.newSuitableFood)` will compile and work.

Comment: I don't get point #1, there's a 'new' right there, right in your copy of my code. Can you indicate which line is flawed? I've added line numbers to the original to help. Re your 2nd point, "After you fix this, bessy is defined to have type Animal, not Cow, so the compiler doesn't know bessy.SuitableFood is Grass" Indeed! Hence I thought "new bessy.SuitableFood" would return a suitable food because <some_object>.SuitableFood would be a kind of virtual type, so when <some_object> is 'Cow' then 'SuitableFood' would be 'grass'. I don't see the value of PDTs if they don't do this.

Comment: "[2], gives me an error which I don't understand: `scala> bessy.eat(bessy.SuitableFood)`". No `new` here.

Comment: "Hence I thought "new bessy.SuitableFood" would return a suitable food because <some_object>.SuitableFood would be a kind of virtual type" But why would you expect this type to have a constructor without parameters? I've edited the answer to explain how to do this correctly.

Comment: I clearly don't get PDTs. I'll do some more reading. Thanks for your help, I've upvote and accepted your answer.